# How to change the syntax of a decorator() to the @decorator

Tags: javascript, decorator

I know that in TypeScript you can use a specific syntax for the decorator pattern: @decorator(). I was wondering how that syntax works behind the hood.

How does the @ sign turn into a decorator function? Could this also be done in vanilla JavaScript? If so: how?

I know it would probably:

- recognise the @
- recognise what object follows
- transform it to `new decorator( logger )`

Below an example as clarification

```js
class Logger {
  message = null;
  log() {
    return this.message;
  }  
}

class Greeter extends Logger {
  message = 'hello';
}

class LoggerDecorator extends Logger {
  constructor( logger ) {
    super();
    this.logger = logger;
  }
  log() {
    return this.logger.message += ' StackOverflow';
  }
  
}

// example
greeter = new LoggerDecorator( new Greeter() );
console.log( greeter.log() === 'hello StackOverflow' );

greeter = new Greeter();
// @LoggerDecorator()
greeter;
// @LoggerDecorator() should do the same as new LoggerDecorator( greeter )

console.log( greeter.log() === 'hello StackOverflow' );
```

Comment: Why not look at the JavaScript that's generated? You can do it [at the TypeScript playground.](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/)

Comment: @Pointy I am curious whether it is possible to implement similar syntax in vanilla JS.  The playground output just returns an example of how to implement a decorator without that syntax. ( Thanks for the suggestion however )

Comment: There's a [proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators) for decorators in plain JavaScript.

Comment: Actually afaik `@decorator something` is equivalent to `decorator(something)`, and `@decorator() something` is equivalent to `decorator()(something)`. There's no `new` involved.